# simulating a grep in Java (Windows)

Tags: java, regex, windows-7

I have to look for a string "Languages: " with languages after it.

I could for instance look for "Languages: English, German" and
"Languages: German, English" if there are only 2 languages.  If there are 3 I would need to look for 6 different combinations.  For 4 there would be 24 combinations.  For 5 there would be 120, etc., which is unwieldly.

I would like to do something like

grep Languages | grep English | grep German | grep Italian | grep Danish | grep French
(or whatever the languages I am looking for would be).  I don't think we can use grep on windows.  I could use a regular expression but I don't know how to create one that could list languages in any order.

Any suggestions on what to do?  Let's say I have a **List< String > languages** with all the languages I want to look for.

Comment: Are you asking how to search text files from Java? If so, are you *sure* you couldn't find an example by searching the web? --- Also, which part of the [regex `|` construct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical) is confusing you?

Comment: No.  I have the text in a string.  I suppose it would be similar.  I know how to do the macth and the contains and even replace, but I don't understand /know how to specify several strings, either of which could come in each order.

Comment: If you have the text in a string, why would you want to run `grep`, which is a command-line program separate from Java? --- As for your statement *"I could use a regular expression but I don't know how to create one that could list languages in any order"*, I'll ask again: which part of the regex `|` construct is confusing you? Maybe you should learn more about regex, instead of asking us to write it for you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to compare two [Sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Strings.  Convert your list of target languages to a Set, and parse each line of your input text and place its list of languages in a new Set, and compare them using `equals`.  (HashSet is an adequate Set implementation for this.)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an idea to get you started. Hope you can develop it.

```
    boolean english = false;
    boolean danish = false;
    boolean hopi = false;
    boolean mandarin = false;
    if (inputString.contains("Languages: ")) {
        if (inputString.contains("English")) {
            english = true;
        }
        if (inputString.contains("Danish")) {
            danish = true;
        }
        if (inputString.contains("Hopi")) {
            hopi = true;
        }
        if (inputString.contains("Mandarin")) {
            mandarin = true;
        }
        System.out.println("English? " + english + " Danish? " + danish + " Hopi? " + hopi + " Mandarin? " + mandarin);
    }
```

If there are more than three or five languages, you will probably want some abstraction over them, maybe a class or enum to represent the languages you support. An `EnumSet` might be convenient for representing which languages are in your string, ignoring the order?

By the way, you noticed that you don’t need regular expressions?

Edit: if you have a `List<String> languageList`, you may want to do like:

```
    Set<String> languagesInInput = new HashSet<>();
    for (String language : languageList) {
        if (inputString.contains(language)) {
            languagesInInput.add(language);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to make that comment.  It would be nice if I could do one contains and put all the languages into one string to check, but they would have to be in any order s I do not think they are necessarily alphabetical.  I could do something like String txt = pageText.replaceAll(".*Languages", "Laungages").replaceAll("\\n.*$","") which will get me the languages string.  Then I could use split with a , and put them into an array and then into a set and compare the sets